# How to use routes in Bloc Login Flutter for NavigationDrawer with authentication

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, bloc

I implemented the Flutter Bloc Login example exactly like guide page [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial):

next, I added a NavigationDrawer to my pages.

but I don't know how to navigate across pages, I tried normal **Navigator.push** but doesn't work and I used **routes** in the MaterialApp and unfortunately it didn't work that way.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  final userRepository = UserRepository();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository)
          ..add(AppStarted());
      },
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserRepository userRepository;
  App({Key key, @required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            //return Counter();
            //return ListPage();
            return ProfilePage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          return SplashPage();
        },
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SplashPage(),
        '/counter': (context) => Counter(),
        '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
        '/list': (context) => ListPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**navigation_drawer.dart**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(...),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () {
              /* TODO: check token is not null */
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');

              },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Counter'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/counter');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('My List'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/list');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you forgot to use **Scaffold** widget as a child of **Material** widget and Scaffold has a property drawer you can pass your drawer to it. like below:

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  final userRepository = UserRepository();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository)
          ..add(AppStarted());
      },
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserRepository userRepository;
  App({Key key, @required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: build(context),
        body: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
              //return Counter();
              //return ListPage();
              return ProfilePage();
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
              return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
              return LoadingIndicator();
            }
            return SplashPage();
          },
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SplashPage(),
        '/counter': (context) => Counter(),
        '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
        '/list': (context) => ListPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**navigation_drawer.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(...),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Profile'),
          onTap: () {
            /* TODO: check token is not null */
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');

          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Counter'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/counter');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('My List'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/list');
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

but I won't suggest you to work with bloc this way.